# Aggregate Spark standalone executor logs

Tags: apache-spark, logging, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit, spark3

I am trying to test spark-submit standalone mode and running below example task

```
spark-submit \
    --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --master spark://MBP-49F32N-CSP.local:7077 \
    --driver-memory 3g \
    --executor-memory 3g \
    --num-executors 2 \
    --executor-cores 2 \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false \
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.5.0/libexec/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.0.jar \
    10
```

And i can see logs generated under

> /apache-spark/3.5.0/libexec/work

I can see directories with application-id

> app-20230929175322-0003   app-20231003110238-0000

And inside app-20231003110238-0000 there are sub-directories
**0 1   2   3   4   5** which are named after executors.
and inside each directory i can see ***stderr   stdout***

Is there any way to aggregate all **executor logs** under application-id(ex=app-20231003110238-0000) directory?

like when we run spark in yarn mode we see all logs under
yarn logs -applicationId <application_ID>

Answer (score 0):

You can have a shell script to aggregate all the stdout and stderr logs, similar to the below.

```
cd /apache-spark/3.5.0/libexec/work/<app_id>

# Concatenate executor stderr logs
cat */stderr > agg_stderr.log

# Concatenate executor stdout logs
cat */stdout > agg_stdout.log
```